# C++ Singleton - Cannot set ```static Singleton _instance = new Singleton();``` - no operator "=" matches these operands

Tags: c++, singleton

Visual Studio 2022 error at `if (_instance == NULL)` and `_instance = new MySingleton();`

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class MySingleton
{
public:
    static MySingleton* Instance()
    {
        if (_instance == NULL)
        {
            _instance = new MySingleton();
        }
        return &_instance;
    }
    static void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "Singleton\n";
    }
protected:
    MySingleton() {}

private:
    static MySingleton _instance
```

Comment: `_instance` should be a pointer, not an instance, VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not a pointer:

```
static MySingleton _instance
```

It should have been:

```
static MySingleton* _instance;
```

... but, instead of checking if a pointer is `NULL` and then calling `new` (which is not thread safe, just have a `static` variable inside the `static Instance()` function - and return it by reference. Users can then bind to that instead of dealing with pointers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MySingleton {
public:
    static MySingleton& Instance() {
        static MySingleton instance;   // thread safe instantiation
        return instance;
    }

    static void Print() { std::cout << "Singleton\n"; }

private:
    MySingleton() {}
};
```

For further reading, this pattern is usually known as "Meyers' Singleton" named after author Scott Meyers.

Used as such:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto& s = MySingleton::Instance();
    s.Print();
}
```

If you insist on using a pointer, then return a pointer but keep the `static` instance inside the function:

```cpp
    static MySingleton* Instance() {
        static MySingleton instance;  // still thread safe
        return &instance;
    }
```